# Destructor is not being invoked

Tags: c++, algorithm, oop, stack, destructor

I have written the following code to implement a stack.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class stack
{
    public:
        int *top;
        int  size, capacity;
    
    stack(int c):capacity(c){
        size = 0;
        top = new int[capacity];
        capacity = capacity - 1;
    }
    
    ~stack() // deleting the stack at the end of program
    {
        delete[] top;
        top = NULL;
        cout << "deleted the stack" << endl;
    }
    
    void push(int data)
    {
        // Is there is a space
        if(is_stackFull())
        {
            cout << "stack is full" << endl;
            return;
        }
        
        // populate the data
        *top   = data;
        
        // updating the stack variables
         top  += 1;
         size += 1;
        return;
    }
    
    void pop()
    {
        // is stack empty
        if(is_stackEmpty())
        {
            cout << "stack is empty" << endl;
            return; 
        }
        
        // update the stack variables
        top  -= 1;
        size -= 1;
        
        return;
    }
    
    bool is_stackFull()
    {
        return (size == capacity);
    }
    
    bool is_stackEmpty()
    {
        return (size == 0);
    }
};


int main()
{
    stack s(10);
    s.push(15);
    //s.pop(); // what happens to the output when i comment out this code?
    
    return 0;
}
```

In the code, the destructor is not being invoked when I commented the s.pop() method.

Can any one explain the tech reason behind such behavior?

I tried understanding the ways to invoke the destructor in a C++ class.

Comment: `push` increments the `top` pointer so it no longer points the the beginning of the memory you allocated. Trying to delete it is undefined behavior. https://godbolt.org/z/7Phr5q3hv You need to come up with a different scheme to ensure you always have access to the initial allocation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The destructor *is* being invoked, it's just not doing what you expect. When you call `push` but not `pop`, `top` ends up pointing one space to the right of where it started. So, the destructor ends up calling [`delete`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete) on a different address from the one returned by `new`, which is [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). That means your code can basically do whatever it wants, which in this case apparently means not printing your `deleted the stack` message. When I run it, I get

```
free(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)
```

To fix it, you could add a line `top -= size` to your destructor before you call `delete` so that it is pointing to the same place it started.

Comment: Doing this math seems like a much more fragile solution that simply not changing what the `data` pointer points to.

Comment: You're probably right... I just felt like the pointer arithmetic was a better illustration of the concepts involved without adding any other distractions. If the goal was to make the cleanest program possible, the best choice would of course be to just use `std::stack`.

Answer (score 4):

In `stack::push` you are changing what `top` points to. Thus it can no longer be deleted. If you push once *and* pop once, `top` goes back to what it was, and the error does not occur.

Rather than modifying the `top` pointer, you can keep track of a top *index* and modify that. E.g.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <optional>

template <class T>
class Stack {
    public:
    using size_type = std::size_t;

    // Constructor
    Stack(size_type cap)
    : capacity(cap), top(0), data(new T[cap])
    { }

    // Destructor
    ~Stack() {
        delete[] data;
    }

    // Copy constructor
    Stack(const Stack& s)
    : capacity(s.capacity), top(s.top), data(new T[s.capacity])
    {
        std::copy(s.data, s.data+capacity, data);
    }

    // Copy assignment
    Stack& operator=(const Stack& s) {
        top = s.top;
        capacity = s.capacity;
        delete[] data;
        data = new T[capacity];
        std::copy(s.data, s.data+capacity, data);
        return *this;
    }

    // Move constructor
    Stack(Stack&& s)
    : capacity(s.capacity), top(s.top), data(s.data)
    {
        s.capacity = 0;
        s.top = 0;
        s.data = nullptr;
    }

    size_type get_capacity() const { return capacity; }
    size_type get_top() const { return top; }
    bool is_empty() const { return top == 0; }
    bool is_full() const { return top == capacity; }

    bool push(T val) {
        if (is_full()) return false;

        data[top++] = val;
        return true;
    }

    std::optional<T> pop() {
        if (is_empty()) return std::nullopt;

        return std::optional<T>{data[--top]};
    }

    private:
    T *data;
    size_type top;
    size_type capacity;
};

int main() {
    auto s = Stack<int>(10);

    s.push(19);
    s.push(67);

    std::cout << s.pop().value() << " "
              << s.pop().value() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for reframing my post and giving an appropriate reply.

Answer (score 1):

The descructor is actually called, but it doesn't reach the `cout << "deleted the stack" << endl;` line. It failed when you `delete[] top`. Why? Because `top` is not a valid pointer. Rather, the `top` is pointing into the valid pointer you allocated during constructor + 4. So, imagine your `top` when creating the stack was `0x004`, after you push a value using `s.push(15)`, it becomes `0x008` (assuming int is 4 bytes long), and when you tried to delete it, you tried to delete `0x008` which is not a valid allocated memory address, the valid one is `0x004`. Thus, your program exit before it prints the `deleted the stack` because you tried to free an invalid address.